# How to optimize when searching multiple objects for a value?

Tags: php, object, optimization, iteration, scanning

Hope everything is good.

Let's say I have this object x 200 (with different values, of course)

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Manufacturer] => Nike
        [Name] => Air Max Talldress
        [Options] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Black] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Medium
                        [1] => Large
                    )

                [White] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Small
                    )

            )

    )
```

I only want all objects where "Manufacturer = Nike". How should I do to ONLY compare with the "Manufacturer" property, without wasting time on properties that are not relevant in this case. Optimize the process.

I'm not interested in dbms, I want to see what's possible here.

//
Neo

Comment: What's the source of this data? Can you filter it in say a database engine before it becomes a PHP object?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you on your way...

To recreate the problem and verify the filter works, I have created a dummy array with manufacturers and generated 100 dummy data 'objects' to iterate over and find the ones holding a certain manufacturer.

```
<?php
$mans = ['Nike', 'Adidas', 'New Balance', 'Under Armour', 'Skechers', 'Asics', 'Saucony', 'Diadora', 'Fila', 'Anta'];
$arr = [];

// create a bunch of dummy data 'objects'
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
foreach($mans as $key => $name) {
    $arr[] = array("0" => (object)[
        "Manufacturer" => $name,
        "Name" => 'some model made by ' . $name,
        "Options" => (object)[
            "Black" => Array
            (
                "0" => 'Medium',
                "1" => 'Large',
            ),
            "White" => Array
            (
                "0" => 'Small'
            )]
    ]
    );
}
}


// filter for a manufacturer
$manufacturer = 'Nike'; // this is the manufacturer we are looking for
$result = filterMans($manufacturer, $arr); // $result is the array with all objects with the manufacturer we're looking for
$hits = count($result); // for each manufacturer in our list we get 10 hits

echo 'your search for objects with manufacturer ' . $manufacturer . ' returned ' . $hits . ' results';
echo '<br />';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';

function filterMans($needle, $haystack)
{
    $result = null;
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if($value[0]->Manufacturer === $needle) {
            $result[] = $value[0];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```